# journalctl -b -1 always shows the same log?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, raspberry-pi, journalctl

When reading the manual for `journalctl` I get the impression that `-b -1` will show the boot one before the most recent.

When I use it I'm always shown the same log. Did I misunderstand something? I've rebooted and tried again multiple times — always the same log with the same events at the exact same times.

###### Update

I've tried vacuuming all the logs, and after a reboot `journalctl` presents me with a log ending with "Shutting down" and "Journal stopped". I don't understand that either. Shouldn't it show me the log of the current boot?

###### Update 2

`journalctl` shows different logs when using `-f` and using `-b -0 -f`. I don't know why. The manual says it should be the same unless you load some custom log directory. I'm not doing anything like that.

I feel like I'm troubleshooting the tool meant to help me troubleshoot my actual problem and that there's no end in sight. I hope I'm just making some simple mistake.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: But `journalctl -b` does show only your logging since your current boot, right? Also worth checking whether `journalctl -e` shows recent Log entries

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nice timing, I just added that detail. It shows me a log of a boot that has shut down...

Comment: Huh! That's not great, I guess. You're not experiencing any storage problems?

Comment: @MarcusMüller `journalctl` shows different logs when using `-f` and using `-b -0 -f`... The latter shows me the current active log; the former does not. Also, when answering you before I assumed `journalctl` = `journalctl -b` = `journalctl -b -0`